# Paillier algorithm encryption

Tags: java, encryption, text

Can any one tell me how to implement paillier algorithm for an file that i am uploading this is my code..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Paillier {
//*******************************paillier encryption******************************
private BigInteger p, q, lambda;
/**
* n = p*q, where p and q are two large primes.
*/
public BigInteger n;
/**
* nsquare = n*n
*/
public BigInteger nsquare;
/**
* a random integer in Z*_{n^2} where gcd (L(g^lambda mod n^2), n) = 1.
*/
private BigInteger g;
/**
* number of bits of modulus
*/
private int bitLength;

/**
* Constructs an instance of the Paillier cryptosystem.
* @param bitLengthVal number of bits of modulus
* @param certainty The probability that the new BigInteger represents a prime number will exceed (1 - 2^(-certainty)). The execution time of this constructor is proportional to the value of this parameter.
*/
public Paillier(int bitLengthVal, int certainty) {
KeyGeneration(bitLengthVal, certainty);
}

/**
* Constructs an instance of the Paillier cryptosystem with 1024 or 512 bits of modulus and at least 1-2^(-64) certainty of primes generation.
*/
public Paillier() {
KeyGeneration(512, 64);
}

/**
* Sets up the public key and private key.
* @param bitLengthVal number of bits of modulus.
* @param certainty The probability that the new BigInteger represents a prime number will exceed (1 - 2^(-certainty)). The execution time of this constructor is proportional to the value of this parameter.
*/
public void KeyGeneration(int bitLengthVal, int certainty) {
bitLength = bitLengthVal;
/*Constructs two randomly generated positive BigIntegers that are probably prime, with the specified bitLength and certainty.*/
p = new BigInteger(bitLength / 2, certainty, new Random());
q = new BigInteger(bitLength / 2, certainty, new Random());

n = p.multiply(q);
nsquare = n.multiply(n);

g = new BigInteger("2");
lambda = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).divide(
p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).gcd(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
/* check whether g is good.*/
if (g.modPow(lambda, nsquare).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(n).gcd(n).intValue() != 1) {
System.out.println("g is not good. Choose g again.");
System.exit(1);
}
}

/**
* Encrypts plaintext m. ciphertext c = g^m * r^n mod n^2. This function explicitly requires random input r to help with encryption.
* @param m plaintext as a BigInteger
* @param r random plaintext to help with encryption
* @return ciphertext as a BigInteger
*/
public BigInteger Encryption(BigInteger m, BigInteger r) {
return g.modPow(m, nsquare).multiply(r.modPow(n, nsquare)).mod(nsquare);
}

/**
* Encrypts plaintext m. ciphertext c = g^m * r^n mod n^2. This function automatically generates random input r (to help with encryption).
* @param m plaintext as a BigInteger
* @return ciphertext as a BigInteger
*/
public BigInteger Encryption(BigInteger m) {
BigInteger r = new BigInteger(bitLength, new Random());
return g.modPow(m, nsquare).multiply(r.modPow(n, nsquare)).mod(nsquare);

}

/**
* Decrypts ciphertext c. plaintext m = L(c^lambda mod n^2) * u mod n, where u = (L(g^lambda mod n^2))^(-1) mod n.
* @param c ciphertext as a BigInteger
* @return plaintext as a BigInteger
*/
public BigInteger Decryption(BigInteger c) {
BigInteger u = g.modPow(lambda, nsquare).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(n).modInverse(n);
return c.modPow(lambda, nsquare).subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(n).multiply(u).mod(n);
}


//********************************file part main************************
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //******************paillier***************
    Paillier paillier = new Paillier();


    //********************file part**************
    File file = new File(args[0]);//path of file
    if (!file.exists()) {
      System.out.println(args[0] + " does not exist.");
      return;
    }
    if (!(file.isFile() && file.canRead())) {
      System.out.println(file.getName() + " cannot be read from.");
      return;
    }
    try {
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
      char msg;
String m1;
      while (fis.available() > 0) {
        msg = (char) fis.read();
      // System.out.print(msg);

     m1=Character.toString(msg);
     //System.out.print(m1);//plain text
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(m1.getBytes());
//System.out.print(bi);//bit converted text
//System.out.print(new String(bi.toByteArray()));//regained plain text 
/* instantiating two plaintext msgs*/

BigInteger m = new BigInteger("bi");
BigInteger m2 = new BigInteger("1");
/* encryption*/
BigInteger em1 = paillier.Encryption(m);
BigInteger em2 = paillier.Encryption(m2);
System.out.println(paillier.Decryption(em1).toString());
//System.out.println(paillier.Decryption(em2).toString());

      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

here i want to make my file charaters to bigints and encrypt but i dont have an idea of doing it please resolve this issue i am sending the plaint text say "Thanking you" in a file sample.txt using command line arguments

Comment: What @yyyyyyy said. Now, I'm going to ask the cryptography related question, why would you want to do this?

Comment: i want to try paillier encryption for an file for my cloud based security project

Comment: Are you using the homomorphic properties Paillier for something? Public key crypto is rarely used for encrypting files.

Comment: homomorphic paillier

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://github.com/kunerd/jpaillier.

Answer (score 2):

I thought you might appreciate three snippets of code from an old project of mine:

#### Private Key Generation

These methods are members of the class `PaillierPrivateKey`.

Note that I am not using $\lambda = \varphi(n)$ but a multiple of this number, `d`, that is congruent to 1 modulo `n`. This way, if I raise a ciphertext $m(n+1)r^n$ to the power `d`, we are left with only $m(n+1)$.

Also, this method returns a private key. To get the public key from this tuple, just use `n`.

```
/**
 * generate
 * generate a private key for the Paillier cryptosystem where the
 * primes have bitLength bits
 * @param bitLength
 * @return
 */
public static PaillierPrivateKey generate(int bitLength)
{
    BigInteger p = new SafePrime(bitLength);
    BigInteger q = new SafePrime(bitLength);
    return generate( p, q );
}
public static PaillierPrivateKey generate(BigInteger p, BigInteger q)
{
    BigInteger n = p.multiply(q);
    BigInteger m = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2))
                    .multiply( q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2)));
    BigInteger d = m.modInverse(n).multiply(m).mod(n.multiply(n));
    return new PaillierPrivateKey( n, d );
}
```

#### Encryption

These methods are members of the class `PaillierPublicKey`. The function `getProduct()` returns $n$, whereas `getModulus()` returns $n^2$ and `getGenerator()` returns $n+1$. The class constructor `RandomInvertibleBigInteger` takes a modulus (i.e., $n^2$) and returns a random integer from the range ${1, ..., n^2}$ and makes sure it is invertible under multiplication modulo $n^2$. (For practical $n$ of some thousand bits, random selection is fine; for small toy examples, you want to filter out zero-divisors.)

```
@Override
public BigInteger encrypt(BigInteger plaintext)
{
    BigInteger rand = new RandomInvertibleBigInteger( getProduct() );
    return encrypt(plaintext, rand);
}

public BigInteger encrypt(BigInteger plaintext, BigInteger rand)
{
    BigInteger gm = getGenerator().modPow(plaintext,getModulus());
    BigInteger rns = rand.modPow(getProduct(), getModulus());
    BigInteger gmrns = gm.multiply(rns);
    BigInteger ciphertext = gmrns.mod(getModulus());
    return ciphertext;
}
```

#### Decryption

This method is also a member of `PaillierPrivateKey`. Once again, `getModulus()` returns $n^2$ whereas `getProduct()` returns $n$. the function `getPrivateExponent()` returns the nifty integer `d` described above.

```
public BigInteger decrypt( BigInteger ciphertext )
{
    return ciphertext.modPow(   getPrivateExponent(),
                                getModulus() )
                            .subtract(BigInteger.ONE)
                            .divide(getProduct());
}
```